# GenemuFormBundle Autocomplete results

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony, autocomplete

I'm currently using GenemuFormBundle to select an entity. Let's say I want to select the entity "watermelon". If I just type "w" in the input, it displays a list, and with every other letter that I type, the list shortens until it only displays "watermelon".

Now let's say I type in "waterme", and that the only result displayed in the list in "watermelon" For now, it I submit the form, it will look for an entity called "waterme", won't find it, and return "NULL".

So, my question is, is it possible to automatically select the first result displayed in the list when my user validates form or focuses another input ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little complicated you have to keep the state of the select2 dropdown somewhere, and when the form is submit, select the element you want, if no element is selected before the before the form is submitted.Here it goes:

```
var currentChoice = null;
var $form = $("#your-form");
var $s2 = $("#your-select2-element");
$s2.on("select2-highlighting", function(event){
  // this event is fired, when some choice is highlighted
  // now store the current choice so we can retrieve it later
  currentChoice = event.val;
});
$form.on('submit', function(){
  //select something if it is not selected, and we have some highlighted choice
  if (!$s2.select2('val') && currentChoice)
    $s2.select2('val',currentChoice);
});
```